# Problema con html y dompdf

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade, dompdf

El problema se produce al crear el pdf:
No alinea los importes a la derecha y debajo de su columna correspondiente
el pdf  presenta debajo de las columnas fecha,asiento y concepto los conceptos que debe presentar y debajo de la  columna debe los importes correspondientes a la columna haber y a la columna saldos

visualmente sería fecha      Asiento concepto  debe     haber        saldo
y los datos       01.01.2020    1     inicial   50,00
                  01.01.2020    2     cobro     25,00
Que debería aparecer debajo de su columna  haber 
este importe corresponde    al saldo            25,00
Y debería aparecer en su posición o sea debajo de la columna saldo

Espero haberme explicado.
El fichero vista.blade es el siguiente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> 'LISTADOS E iNFORMES' </title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    td { color: black;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size: 80%; }
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Cuenta___ {{$subcuenta}}   </h1>   
      <table>
      <head>
      <tr>
      <th>
      Fecha
      </th>
      <th>
      Asiento
      </th>
      <th>
      concepto
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>
      Debe
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>
       Haber
       </th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th>
       Saldo
       </th>
       </tr>    
       </head>
       <body>
       @foreach($lineas as $linea)
       <tr>
       <td>
       {{App\Helpers\Date::reverseDate2($linea->fecha) }}
       </td>
       <td>
       {{$linea->asiento}}
       @if($linea->imported>0)
      {{ $linea->concepto()->concepto."   ".$linea->extensionconcepto }}
      {{number_format($linea->imported,2,",",".")}}
      {{$linea->saldo}}
      @else
      {{ $linea->conceptodos()->concepto."   ".$linea->extensionconceptodos }}
      {{ number_format($linea->importeh,2,",","." ) }}
      {{$linea->saldo}}
      @endif   
    </td>
   <br>
  </tr>
  @endforeach    
 </body>    
 </table>
<body>

</html>
```

Y el fichero app.css es el siguiente

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    border:1 px solid #333;
}
td{
                padding: 5 px;
    text-align: left;
}
th{
        text-align: center;
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes tener mal maquetado el documento de entrada o que se desordene si falta algún dato. **Paso 1.** Crea el documento HTML con datos irreales y maquetalo correctamente. **Paso 2.** Comprueba que te llegan todos los datos estrictamente necesario o un string vacío en su lugar.

Comment: Perfecto. Estaba mal maquetado siempre faltaba un dato

Comment: Seria bueno saber cual es el resultado que te arroja el PDF

Comment: Hola.Perdona la tardanza;el resultado es un fichero de Adobe Acrobat Document de:http:LocalHost  que:O bien lo deja en descargas o bien se abre con Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (predeterminado),y hoy precisamente lo he tenido que abrir firefox